# How to capture part of name without optional group

Tags: regex

I'm adding information about part and version of the process (some of them are without this information) and i want to capture name of process- how can i do it?

I was trying to use pattern: `(.+)(?:p\d+ v\d+)?$`, but it doesn't work

Sample of names:

Process name 1

Other proces 2 p1 v35

Process 1 does sth p32 v5

Inputs:

Other process 2 p1 v35
Process 1

Results (expected)

Other process 2

process name 1

Comment: What do you mean by *it doesn't work*?

Comment: Also, please include some varied inputs and their desired results.

Comment: It captures whole input

Comment: `(.+)` will match everything it can, and you made the second group `(?:p\d+ v\d+)` optional, so the `.+` will match the entire string until the `$`. This regex will match the entire input for any string you throw at it.

Comment: I now about it. That,s why i`m for regex solution, which captures only name before this optional group

Comment: You must use the MULTILINE option. That way '$' will match each end of line. Now it matches end of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
^(.+?)(?=p\d+\s*v\d+\s*$|$)
```

As seen **[here](https://regex101.com/r/KkOtm2/2)**

## Explanation:

I used a positive lookahead, which you can learn more about by **[clicking on this link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**.

Basically, I match everything from the start of the line, until the point where you get a `p1 v35`, or until the end of the line.